# How I implement reset_cooldown in a cog file?

Tags: python-3.x, command, discord, discord.py

I m trying to do a command with which my friends can troll each other by moving them to a special channel.
I put a cooldown so they won t abuse it but know, when i m trying to rewrite my code to a cog version i can t handle the `@command.after_invoke`  so i can t reset cooldown if the author is me or someone special.
I tried to do it in `@command.error` but if i reset it there i can t reactivate it
My problem is that i can t figure out how am i suppose to transpose this into a cog version:

```
@m.after_invoke
async def reset_cooldown(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.id==1234567890:
        m.reset_cooldown(ctx)
```

I ll put cog file with my function, it works but thw down is that i can t reset cooldown:

```
import discord

from datetime import datetime

protected=[1234567890]


class move(commands.Cog):


    def __init__(self,bot):

        self.bot=bot


    @commands.command(pass_context=True,aliases=['m'])
    @commands.cooldown(1,300,commands.BucketType.user)
    async def move(self,ctx,member:discord.Member):

        global protected

        message=ctx.message
        delete_module=self.bot.get_cog('delete') #this will erase the message so the victim won  tknow who s doing teh prank
        await delete_module.delete(ctx,ctx.author)

        canal_sclav=list(filter(lambda x: x.name=='sclav',ctx.guild.voice_channels))[0] # this is the channel where they llbe sent
        reports=list(filter(lambda x: x.id==1234567890,member.guild.channels))[0] # this is a channel in which i track the activity
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")



        embed=discord.Embed(description=message.author.mention+'l-a maltrafoxat pe '+member.mention+ ' la ora '+current_time,color=discord.Colour.red()) # this is the sign that someone was abused
        

        ########################     daca autorul nu e conectat -- if the author is not connected
        if ctx.author.voice==None:

            embed=discord.Embed(description=message.author.mention+'Conecteza-te fiti-ar alifia de ras',color=discord.Colour.gold())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        ########################     daca beleste pe cine nu trebuie -- this is for the protected one
        elif member.id in protected:

            embed=discord.Embed(description=message.author.mention+' altadata, suge-o acum',color=discord.Colour.gold())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        ########################     daca membrul nu e conectat -- if member is not connected
        elif member.voice==None:

            embed=discord.Embed(description=message.author.mention+' nu poate fi babardit incearca alt fraier',color=discord.Colour.gold())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        ########################     daca membrul e pe sclav -- if he is abused
        elif member.voice.channel==canal_sclav:

            embed=discord.Embed(description=message.author.mention+' si-o ia in cur schimba prostu',color=discord.Colour.gold())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        ########################     daca e ok -- if it is ok 
        else:
            await reports.send(embed=embed)
            await member.move_to(canal_sclav)

            embed=discord.Embed(description=member.mention+' este abuzat',color=discord.Colour.gold())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)


    # for error handling 
    @move.error
    async def move_error(self,ctx,error):
        global protected


        retry_after = round(error.retry_after)
        text=ctx.message.author.mention+' ti-o pot suge in  '+str(round(error.retry_after))+'s'
        embed=discord.Embed(description=text,color=discord.Colour.magenta())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed
        )
            # f"\N{HOURGLASS} Command is on cooldown, try again after {retry_after} seconds"

    # HERE I TRIED TO DO IT BUT I CAN T FIND ENOUGH RESOURCES
    @move.afetr_invoke
    async def reset_cooldown(ctx):

        if ctx.message.author.id in protected:

            move.reset_cooldown(ctx)




def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(move(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer; the reset function that should be add is this:

```
async def cog_after_invoke(self,ctx):

        if ctx.message.author.id in protejati:

            ctx.command.reset_cooldown(ctx)
```